# Does the inline asm compiler barrier (memory clobber) count as an external function, or as static function call?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, inline-assembly, memory-barriers

### Introduction/confirmation of basic facts

It is well known that with GCC style C and C++ compilers, you can use inline assembly with a "memory" clobber:

```
asm("":::"memory");
```

to prevent reordering of (most) code past it, acting as a (thread local) "memory barrier" (for example for the purpose of interacting with async signals).

*Note: these "compiler barriers" do NOT accomplish inter-threads synchronization.*

It does the equivalent of a call to a non inline function, potentially reading all objects that can be read outside of the current scope and altering all those that can be altered (non const objects):

```
int i;

void f() {
   int j = i;
   asm("":::"memory"); // can change i
   j += i; // not j *= 2
   // ... (assume j isn't unused)
}
```

Essentially it's the same as calling a NOP function that's separately compiled, except that the non inline NOP function call is later (1) inlined so nothing survives from it.

(1) say, after compiler middle pass, after analysis

So here `j` cannot be changed as it's local, and is still the copy of the old `i` value, but `i` might have changed, so the compilation is pretty much the same as:

```
volatile int vi;

int f2() {
   int j = vi;
   ; // can "change" vi
   j += vi; // not j *= 2
   return j;
}
```

Both reads of `vi` are needed (for a different reason) so the compiler doesn't change that into `2*vi`.

Is my understanding correct up to that point? (I presume it is. Otherwise the question doesn't make sense.)

### The real issue: extern or static

The above was just the preamble. The issue I have is with static variables, possible calls to static functions (or the C++ equivalent, anonymous namespaces):

**Can a memory clobber access static data** that isn't otherwise accessible via non static functions, and call static functions that aren't otherwise callable, as none of these are visible at link stage, from other modules, **if they aren't named explicitly in the input arguments of the asm directive?**

```
static int si;

int f3() {
   int j = si;
   asm("":::"memory"); // can access si?
   j += si; // optimized to j = si*2; ?
   return j;
}
```

[Note: the use of static is a little ambiguous. The suggestion is that the boundary of the TU is important, and that the static variable is TU-private, but I have not described how it was manipulated. Let's assume it is really manipulated that in that TU, or the compiler might assume it's effectively a constant.]

In other words, is that "clobber" the equivalent of a call to:

- an external NOP function, which wouldn't be able to name `si` directly, nor to access it in any indirect way, as no function in the TU either communicates the address of `si`, or makes `si` indirectly modifiable
- a locally defined NOP function that can access `si`

?

### Bonus question: global optimization

If the answer is that static variables aren't treated like extern variables in that case, what is the impact when compiling the program at once? More specifically:

During global compilation of the whole program, with global analysis and inference over variables values, is the knowledge of the fact that for example a global variable is never modified (or never assigned a negative value...), except possibly in an `asm` "clobber", an input of the optimizer?

In other words, if non static `i` is only named in one TU, can it be optimized as if it was a static `int` even if there are `asm` statements? Should global variables be explicitly listed as clobbers in that case?

Comment: Your understanding is incorrect. The effect of the memory clobber is *not* limited to non-local variables.

Comment: @prl So "memory" here would allow access to `j`? Does that mean that `j` would have to be in its canonical (ABI) representation during the asm statement?

Comment: Does the ABI specify the representation of local variables? I would assume that it does not.

Comment: @prl The C ABI doesn't care about "local"; it specifies the representation of objects created in another module. If your local variable is accessed from another module, it must follow an ABI. If its address is never taken, you are not so constrained. That's why it's better to never allow the address of frequently used variables like loop indexes to escape.

Comment: @prl The ABI is the common ground when you mix compilers and even different languages. Asm is a different language and the assembler is a different compiler, so even inline asm is a mixing that is mediated by the ABI. The contract is that all variables exposed to the asm code have their ABI representation at start of said code. Which variables are exposed by the "memory" clobber?

Comment: @prl It is limited in term of access to automatic objects. [memory effect on automatic GCC 9.2](https://godbolt.org/z/gGCz7G) shows that **"memory" does not clobber local variable `j`**. (Same with clang.)

Comment: @prl: My experience with the effect of `asm("":::"memory")` is that it's exactly like a non-inline function call; only "escaped" locals variables are forced to be in sync in memory because otherwise the asm statement would have no plausible way to read them (e.g. via reading their address from a hypothetical global variable).  If escape analysis proves a variable is truly local; it can ignore the `"memory"` clobber.  To force it into memory, use an `"m"(var)` input operand to the asm statement.

Comment: @curiousguy: untested so not posting an answer yet: IIRC GCC does respect possible modification of `static` variables, at least at global scope.  Maybe not at function scope if they aren't inputs to the asm statement.  But it will optimize them away if possible so use `__attribute__((used))` on them if you want to access a `static` from inline asm.  (Or call a function from asm; unused or always-inlined functions also get optimized away.)

Comment: @PeterCordes There is the unused object elimination angle and then there is the analysis performed on variables mostly manipulated in asm statements. I mostly fear the last one.

Comment: Yeah, I get that.  I *think* if a `static` object isn't removed, it will respect `asm` memory barriers.  Should be pretty straightforward to cook up some test cases to see if it works in simple cases without `volatile`.  Obviously `volatile` doesn't need compiler barriers at all.

Answer (score 0):

> It does the equivalent of a call to a non inline function, potentially reading all objects that can be read outside of the current scope and altering all those that can be altered (non const objects):

No.

The compiler can decide to inline any function in the same compilation unit (and then, if the function wasn't `static`, also provide a separate "not inlined" copy for callers in other compilation units so that the linker can find one); and with link-time code optimization/link-time code generation the linker can decide to inline any functions in different compilation units. The only case where it's currently impossible for any function to be inlined is when it is in a shared library; but this limitation currently exists because operating systems currently aren't capable of "load-time optimization".

In other words; any appearance of any kind of barrier for any function is an unintended side-effect of optimizer weaknesses and not guaranteed; and therefore can not/should not be relied on.

**The real issue: inline assembly**

There are 5 possibilities:

a) The compiler understands all assembly, and is able to examine the inline assembly and determine what is/isn't clobbered; there is no clobber list (and no need for one). In this case (depending on how advanced the compiler/optimiser is) the compiler may be able to determine things like "this area of memory may be clobbered but that area of memory won't be clobbered" and avoid the cost of reloading data from the area of memory that wasn't clobbered.

b) The compiler doesn't understand any assembly and there is no clobber list, so the compiler has to assume everything will be clobbered; which means that the compiler has to generate code that saves the everything (e.g. currently in use values in registers, etc) to memory before the inline assembly is executed and reload everything afterwards, which will give extremely bad performance.

c) The compiler doesn't understand any assembly, and expects the programmer to provide a clobber list to avoid (some of) the performance disaster of having to assume everything will be clobbered.

d) The compiler understands some assembly but not all assembly, and doesn't have a clobber list. If it doesn't understand the assembly it assumes everything may have been clobbered.

e) The compiler understands some assembly but not all assembly, and does have an (optional?) clobber list. If it doesn't understand the assembly it relies on the clobber list (and/or falls back to "assume everything is clobbered" if there is no clobber list), and if it does understand the assembly it ignores the clobber list.

Of course a compiler that uses "option c)" can be improved to use "option e)"; and a compiler that uses "option e)" can be improved to use "option a)".

In other words; any appearance of any kind of barrier for something like "`asm("":::"memory");`" is an unintended side-effect of the compiler being "improvable"; and therefore can not/should not be relied on.

**Summary**

None of the things you've mentioned are actually a barrier of any kind. It's all just "unintended and undesired failure to optimize".

If you do need a barrier, then use an actual barrier (e.g. "`asm("mfence":::"memory");`". However (unless you need inter-threads synchronization and aren't using atomics) its extremely likely that you do not need a barrier in the first place.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `asm("":::"memory")` is actually documented by GCC to work as a compiler barrier.  Having future GCC start parsing the instructions inside the asm template and optimize it out would break that contract.

Comment: Also, I think you're missing the point of "non-inline function call".  We mean a function call that truly *can't* inline because the definition isn't visible to the optimizer during code-gen (separate TU, or not present even with LTO, or must respect possibility of symbol interposition for non-"hidden" symbols.)  *Not* just whether it has the C++ `inline` keyword!

Comment: @PeterCordes: I'm (indirectly) implying that (unless you need inter-threads synchronization and aren't using atomics) its extremely likely that you do not need "no-compile-time-reordering" (ie. that the "as if" rule is all you need). I'm not suggesting anything about any specific compiler (and for GCC I'd expect it to continue being "improvable").

Comment: `asm("":::"memory")` is a roll-your-own implementation of `std::atomic_signal_fence()` in GNU C (gcc/clang/ICC / any other compiler that supports the extensions), and on x86 a roll-your-own implementation of all barriers short of StoreLoad.  I wouldn't normally suggest using it either, but it's a useful question about exactly what it barriers and what it doesn't.  (e.g. whether it forces non-escaped locals to memory: it doesn't now, even in practice.)  Also, the Linux kernel does use it in practice, so it's useful for that reason to know what it does if looking at kernel code.  And microbench

Comment: @PeterCordes: Think about the "load-time optimizer" I mentioned. Immediately before execution all functions are visible (to the CPU) and therefore immediately before execution all functions can be inlined. For example; imagine if all code (in shared libraries, etc) was in LLVM byte-code and the OS did all linking (of shared libraries, etc) and whole program optimisation immediately before execution.

Comment: Ok sure, then there wouldn't be any non-inlinable functions.  That doesn't remove the *concept*, and real-world compilers have to be able to handle that case.  So you can talk about what they *would* do in such a case even if there are no instances of that behaviour for whole-program optimization.

Comment: IDK if I ever read every word of the question, so maybe I'm mistaken and this does answer it.  But I *think* that part of your argument is missing the point, and the part about `asm("":::"memory")` is almost certainly wrong.  Note that it's implicitly `volatile` because it has no output operands.  A compiler that did what you suggest by removing it would be possible, but it wouldn't implement GNU C *correctly*.

Comment: @PeterCordes: If you want to pretend that "GNU C" is a separate language with its own rules , then yes, things that apply to "international standard C" may not apply to "random vendor defined language".

Comment: GNU C is a well-defined dialect of C (supported by a few compilers), and the behaviour of its extensions to the C language are defined on paper by the GCC manual.  The policy is documented = supported.  The docs specify some details about how `asm volatile` and `"memory"` clobbers work so it is useful to ask what that implies.  Asking what `asm("":::"memory")` means in ISO C is clearly not useful; ISO C doesn't define any such thing.

Comment: @PeterCordes: I think you mean: GCC's inline assembly was a lame hack, then (due to C's original lack of any support for threads giving them very little choice) people misused the lame hack (combined with "failure to optimize") for barriers, then GCC developers realized they can't fix "failure to optimize" without breaking existing code that already made the mistake of depending on it, so they decided it would have to become an official "de-facto non-standard" and wrote a paper describing the final symptoms of their "three stooges engineering"?

Comment: The fact is; unless you're doing low-level things (writing a pthreads library, writing freestanding kernel code); relying on `asm("":::"memory")` (instead of using a more abstract and more portable alternative, like a library and/or intrinsic) is a mistake.

Comment: More or less, yes.  Enshrining the behaviour code relies on in the documentation standardizes the result of this happens-to-work evolution.

Comment: *relying on asm("":::"memory") (instead of using a more abstract and more portable alternative, like a library and/or intrinsic) is a mistake* Generally agreed, yes.  Was never trying to argue otherwise.  This documentation / standardization of `asm()` is important for library *implementers*, and maybe people doing microbenchmarks trying to coax GCC into compiling like it might in some more complicated situation.  But for most production code, not relevant.

Comment: Note: The part that annoys me is that "failure to optimize" has become entrenched. CLANG has a built-in assembler for 80x86 that's already capable of auto-detecting the clobber list for most cases, but because of GCC compatibility it's constrained to reporting errors when explicitly provided clobber list was wrong (and can't make the clobber list optional/unnecessary despite being ridiculously close to the "option a)" in my answer).

Comment: Interesting point.  Clang does have `-fasm-blocks` for MSVC-style asm. But then you lose the ability to use register in/out operands so you normally wouldn't want to use it.

Comment: @Brendan How would you even auto-detect the clobber list of a fencing instruction? (Note that it's trap question.)

Comment: @curiousguy: A fencing instruction (in isolation) doesn't clobber anything. The compiler only needs to know that it can't be done before or after other instructions that access memory, and can be done before or after other instructions that don't access memory. Of course compilers like GCC can't be told that (it's either volatile or not - there is no "can be before or after some instructions but not other instructions").

Comment: @Brendan "_A fencing instruction (in isolation) doesn't clobber anything_" In a way yes; "in isolation" an interrupt doesn't "do" anything either. It just lets kernel code to change things. The kernel interrupt handling code might or might not change memory state visible by the program. Same for a `call`, it might or might not return information. "_The compiler only needs to know that it can't be done before or after other instructions that access memory_" I don't follow you. What can be done?

Comment: @curiousguy: Assume you have a sequence of instructions like "`mov eax,[foo]; add ecx,edx; mfence; add ebx,ebp; mov [ebp],esi`", where most of the instructions were generated by the compiler but the `mfence` was from inline assembly. It's perfectly fine (for compiler's optimizer) to change the order of instructions to something like "`mov eax,[foo]; add ecx,edx; add ebx,ebp; mfence; mov [ebp],esi`" but not fine to change the order to "`mov eax,[foo]; add ecx,edx; add ebx,ebp; mov [ebp],esi; mfence`".